# How can I embed python in a bcc64 project?

Tags: python, c++, c++builder

I am porting a project from C++ Embarcadero XE6 32 bit to XE6 64 bit.  We use embedded python libraries (and also some Python modules written in C).

I was able to get it to compile, but I can not link because there aren't any libs in the Python directory that the compiler `bcc64` (a `clang` based compiler) can use.

Here's my code, it's just the simple "Here's how to embed python" example from the documentation really.  We use Python 3.1; we could upgrade but I don't see the libs in newer versions either.

```
#define HAVE_ROUND
#define HAVE_ACOSH
#define HAVE_ASINH
#define HAVE_ATANH

#include <Python.h>

#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <tchar.h>
#else
    typedef char _TCHAR;
    #define _tmain main
#endif

#include <stdio.h>

 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) 
{
    // Invoke the python intepreter
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                                         "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
    Py_Finalize();

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you used the compiler-provided tools to generate a .lib file from the .dll file?

Comment: I have not been able to identify a compiler-provided tool to do that.  I am aware of the `coff2omf.exe` program, but AFAIK that only works for `bcc32`, which is a completely different beast.  `bcc64`, being clang-based, actually uses elf.

Comment: A quick bit of Googling finds a tool called "mkexp".

Comment: Here is Embarcadero's documentation about it: [MKEXP.EXE, the 64-bit Windows Import Library Tool for C++](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/MKEXP.EXE,_the_64-bit_Windows_Import_Library_Tool_for_C%2B%2B)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mkexp libpython31.a C:\Windows\System32\python31.dll`

Thanks to Ignacio for the help.